# Different Results when using batch_size in HuggingFace Pipeline

Tags: python, nlp, pipeline, summary, huggingface

I get very different results (while keeping everything else simililar (ceteris paribus)) when passing prompts to my model sequentually or when batching the prompts.

I am currently using this pieline for summarization:

```
summarize = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",   
    model=model,         
    tokenizer=tokenizer,    
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16, 
    max_new_tokens=512,  
    do_sample=True,         
    top_k=50,      
    top_p=0.95, 
    temperature=0.01
)
```

now i pass the prompts to the pipeline sequentually like this:

```
summaries = []
for prompt in prompts:
    summary = summarize(prompt)
    summaries.append(summary)
```

i get way better results, in comparision to using the batching parameter:

```
summaries = summarize(prompts, batch_size = 4)
```

Does anybody have an explaination for this. It is indeed the case that the sequential pieline generates the better output in 20 out of 20 cases.

Thanks in advance!